# Try to solve the "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value Playground execution failed" problem

Tags: xcode

Im new to xcode and I tried almost anything I could in order to solve the "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value Playground execution failed" problem. aprecciate a lot if you could help me . Thanks

```
//Don't change this
var aYear =  Int(readLine()!)!
func isLeap(year: Int) {
    let year = 1900
    if year.isMultiple(of: 4) {
    print("yes")
    }
}
//Try out your function with some different years. Don't copy the line below (it's not part of the exercise you need to complete).
isLeap(year: aYear)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `aYear` variable is nil. The playground is trying to access this nil value, which causes the playground to fail.

Give `aYear` an initial value, and the playground should run.

```
var aYear = 2021
```

You should also remove the `let year = 1900` line from the `isLeap` function. Use the `year` argument to determine if the year is a leap year.